# Webdriver - Opening a new browser with the same profile

Tags: junit, webdriver

I am running some java tests for a web application with Webdriver on Firefox, trying to verify the functionality of a "Keep me logged in" button. Each time a new browser is launched, it is done so with a new profile. Is there a way to instruct it to open the new browser with the same profile as before, the one that logged in and pressed on "keep me logged in"? I'm sorry if the question doesn't make sense, I'm still a bit new at this.

Thanks,

Ragnar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't currently possible. WebDriver will use a fresh profile every time you launch the browser (although you can use an existing profile as a model). You can file a feature request in the [Selenium tracker](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/entry)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FirefoxProfile` with an existing profile:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(path to profile dir);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Comment: Thank you, but that does not help. I absolutely need to use a fresh profile to login and click the "Keep me logged in" button each time, and then the same profile to load a new page.

Comment: @Ragnar - this last comment conflicts with what you asked in your original question.  in your original question you ask if there is a way to reuse profiles and then in this comment you say "i absolutely need a fresh profile to login".   So, what is it?  What do you really want?   To  me, this answer, by ZloiAdum seems to me to be the correct answer.  You could also copy a fresh profile and then specifically refer to it if you wanted to.

Comment: @djangofan: It's been a couple of years since I asked this question, but I think I wasn't clear enough with that comment. If I remember correctly, what I needed was to use a new profile each time I ran the "Keep Me Logged In" test, i.e. New Profile clicks on Keep Me Logged In, login, close the browser, relaunch the browser, verify that Keep Me Logged In works correctly, close the browser and discard the profile. Rinse & repeat. 

Using an existing profile would have conflicted with the testing requirements of that project.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do that with obtaining a new WebDriver instance.
but you can do that with JavaScript as below

```
((JavascriptExecutor)webDriver).executeScript("window.open('"+ConfigLocator.getTargetServer()+"', '_blank');");
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, like Jarib said, it is possible to use an existing profile as a model. It means no specific data like favorites, history, homepage will be really loaded. But there is a possibility to set some special sytem properties to driver.

```
webdriver.reap_profile
```

Should be “true” if temporary files and profiles **should not be** deleted

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.reap_profile", "true");
```

Most probably there is a possibility to use that kind of solution in your situation too.